# The correct comparative to use in this sentence

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions

Comparative adjectives are adjectives that we used when comparing two nouns, pronouns or objects. We add either 'er' or more to the positive form to give us comparative. e.g Nice-nicer, handsome-more handsome.

What is the correct comparative suitable for this sentence?

> Obi is ........ troublesome than I had imagined.

less, more less, much less, very least.

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: Obi is less troublesome than I had imagined